# How do I end a while True: loop once all possibilities have been printed?

Tags: python, list, loops, random, while-loop

How do I end the loop once all possibilities have been printed?

Sorry if the question is formatted in a bad/annoying way, I'm new so just bear with me.

```
import random
while True:
    comb = random.randint(0,100)
    print(comb)
```

Comment: If you want to make sure you print all the values, then why go through them in a random order, rather than just counting up from 0 to 99? If you want to get those values in a random order, then that is *shuffling* the pre-defined set of values, which is a *different question*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel about the random order: could also use `random.sample(range(100 + 1), k=101)`, but I agree that the question is not quite clear

Answer (score 2):

By all possibilities I assume you want to stop once all numbers between [0, 100] have been printed randomly. In this case, you'd need to keep track of which numbers have been printed so far and break only once you've printed all 100 different values.

```
import random
vals_so_far = set()
while True:
    comb = random.randint(0, 100)
    print(comb)
    vals_so_far.add(comb)
    if len(vals_so_far) == 101:
        break
```

Comment: I think you need a len 101

Comment: Thanks! Fixed - I think in Java it generates a number within [0, 100) but Python apparently includes both ends.

Comment: normally python doesn't include both ends but this is one of those rare cases where it does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Answer (score 1):

I could've just done this:

```
for i in range (1,101):
    print (i)
```

Comment: Hi Spiffy, Do you want to print all of numbers from 1 to 100 consecutively or do you want to print random numbers - like you asked in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep track of the results, and ensure all of them have been printed.
If it is enough to just print the uniquely found values as they are found:

```
import random

comb_values = {}
while len(comb_values) < 101:
    comb = random.randint(0,100)
    print(comb)
    comb_values[comb] = ""

print(len(comb_values))
```

I used a dict called comb_values because it only permits unique values. Once you've got 101 unique values, you have found every number within the range.
You could also do something like increment the value inside the dict to figure out how many times each value was found.

Comment: Note that using a set is better here since it keeps unique values (you are not really using the value of the map here in any meaningful way)

Comment: I agree, but suggested may want to keep track of how many times the numbers appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here I think I have a solution:

```
import random

comb_set = set()
run = True

while run:
    comb = random.randint(0,100)
    print(comb)
    comb_set.add(comb)
    if len(comb_set) == 100:
        run = False
```